# delims and goto not working (batch)

Tags: batch-file

Could somebody tell me why the following isnt working...

```
:PHASE_ONE
SET /P input_text=   ENTER PASSWORD:

for /f "delims=1234567890" %%A in ("%input_text%") GOTO PHASE_ONE
```

Im trying to avoid numerical values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. You are missing a `DO` before your `GOTO`.

However, your logic is also the wrong way round - you are actually ensuring that the password must only be numbers.

The following will restrict it to letters, for example:

```
@ECHO OFF

:PHASE_ONE
SET /P input_text=   ENTER PASSWORD:

for /f "delims=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" %%A in ("%input_text%") DO GOTO PHASE_ONE

ECHO.
```

However, you would be better off using the `FINDSTR` command, such as this:

```
@ECHO OFF

:PHASE_ONE
SET /P input_text=   ENTER PASSWORD:

ECHO %input_text% | FINDSTR /I /R [0-9][0-9]*

REM If Errorlevel is 1, then no matching string has been found,
REM so we have a valid password (i.e. non-numeric).
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO Passed
GOTO PHASE_ONE

:Passed
ECHO Hooray - your password is fine.
```

Comment: I dont do near enougth batch (I ussually build in autolisp for autocad, hens some of the vague questions of late)

Comment: I've added the `FINDSTR` alternative, which uses a regular expression to work out if the password is ok. It's much cleaner.